# Retrieving values using the key from parsed json using jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, json

using a function(below), i'm trying to get the average house price from my JSON data(below), using the passed in region and house type parameters.
I'm ok itterating over and matching on the passed in 'regionName', however I'm then struggling to itterate over the house types (which i believe are the keys in the data) in order to match it against the passed in variable 'literalHouseType', with the aim of then getting that house types price. 
As you maybe able to tell, the function works up until the point it matches on the region in the first loop, after that I'm stuck.
I'm not an avid programmer, so any type of help would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
var jSonData = JSON.stringify([ {
 "Region_Name": "England",
 "Detached_Average_Price": "357425.4953",
 "Semi_Detached_Average_Price": "219615.157",
 "Terraced_Average_Price": "190095.3402",
 "Flat_Average_Price": "222355.8556" },

 {"Region_Name": "Scotland",
 "Detached_Average_Price": "252491.6457",
 "Semi_Detached_Average_Price": "152351.671",
 "Terraced_Average_Price": "121237.8809",
 "Flat_Average_Price": "104417.6462" }
```

Function used:

```
var jSondata = jQuery.parseJSON(jSonData);

$( document ).ready(function() {
GetAveragePriceByHouseTypeAndRegion("Detached_Average_Price", "England");
});

function GetAveragePriceByHouseTypeAndRegion(literalHouseType, regionName) {

for (var i = 0; i < jSondata.length; i++) {
    if (jSondata[i].Region_Name === regionName) {

        for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(jSondata[i]).length; j++) {                
            if (Object.keys(jSondata[i]).value === literalHouseType) {
             //stuck here..   
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: What's an example value of `literalHouseType`?

Comment: Hi, i've updated the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `literalHouseType` will look like `"Detached"` or `"Semi_Detached"`:

```js
var data = [{
    "Region_Name": "England",
    "Detached_Average_Price": "357425.4953",
    "Semi_Detached_Average_Price": "219615.157",
    "Terraced_Average_Price": "190095.3402",
    "Flat_Average_Price": "222355.8556"
  },

  {
    "Region_Name": "Scotland",
    "Detached_Average_Price": "252491.6457",
    "Semi_Detached_Average_Price": "152351.671",
    "Terraced_Average_Price": "121237.8809",
    "Flat_Average_Price": "104417.6462"
  }
];

function getAveragePriceByHouseTypeAndRegion(literalHouseType, regionName) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].Region_Name === regionName) {
      return data[i][literalHouseType + "_Average_Price"];
    }
  }
}

console.log(getAveragePriceByHouseTypeAndRegion("Semi_Detached", "Scotland"));  // 152351.671
```

**EDIT**

Based on the question edit, it looks like a string like `Detached_Average_Price` is being passed in as `literalHouseType`, so the code is slightly simpler:

```js
var data = [{
    "Region_Name": "England",
    "Detached_Average_Price": "357425.4953",
    "Semi_Detached_Average_Price": "219615.157",
    "Terraced_Average_Price": "190095.3402",
    "Flat_Average_Price": "222355.8556"
  },

  {
    "Region_Name": "Scotland",
    "Detached_Average_Price": "252491.6457",
    "Semi_Detached_Average_Price": "152351.671",
    "Terraced_Average_Price": "121237.8809",
    "Flat_Average_Price": "104417.6462"
  }
];

function getAveragePriceByHouseTypeAndRegion(literalHouseType, regionName) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].Region_Name === regionName) {
      return data[i][literalHouseType];
    }
  }
}

console.log(getAveragePriceByHouseTypeAndRegion("Semi_Detached_Average_Price", "Scotland"));  // 152351.671
```

**EDIT 2**

Of course, if you can reshape your data, this is even easier:

```js
var data = {
  "England": {
    "Detached_Average_Price": "357425.4953",
    "Semi_Detached_Average_Price": "219615.157",
    "Terraced_Average_Price": "190095.3402",
    "Flat_Average_Price": "222355.8556"
  },
  "Scotland": {
    "Detached_Average_Price": "252491.6457",
    "Semi_Detached_Average_Price": "152351.671",
    "Terraced_Average_Price": "121237.8809",
    "Flat_Average_Price": "104417.6462"
  }
};

function getAveragePriceByHouseTypeAndRegion(literalHouseType, regionName) {
  return data[regionName][literalHouseType];
}

console.log(getAveragePriceByHouseTypeAndRegion("Semi_Detached_Average_Price", "Scotland")); // 152351.671
```

Comment: Fair play smarx that was a quick reply..
So, the first option worked like a charm, the second more refactored one gave me an error on the return: 
jSondata[regionName][literalHouseType]; << [literalHouseType] reports 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Detached_Average_Price' of undefined'

Comment: Did you change the shape of `data` to match mine?

Comment: No, my bad, forgot that part.... : /
Did however, vote up and accepted answer though, thanks for the assist, appreciate it.